# Url rewriting in .htaccess file in Joomla Site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to write a rule in `.htaccess file`, all I want to do it:
The user will look for following link:
`www.example.com/sitemap.xml` (in browser address bar)

but in reality I want to show the following link:
`www.example.com/index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml`

Comment: the answer below w/o forward slashes and with `[L]` flag

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 RewriteEngine  on
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/sitemap\.xml$ 
RewriteRule .* /index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml [QSA,R,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mod_rewrite`. There are lots of details in the [official docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html). If you don't want the user to see the new URL in the address bar, you should use an internal redirect.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/sitemap\.xml$"  "/index.php?option=com_xmap&view=xml" [PT]
```